# Choosing "stack" for email hosting

Tags: ubuntu, email-server, webmail, email

I plan to host email services on Ubuntu (Is the distribution I'm more familiar with).

I just want to offer really decent email services including:

- Easy account creation by custommer
- Good webmail interface
- Spam filtering.

Is there any paid/free software stack to implement this easily on my s
erver?

Thank you!

Guillermo

Answer (score 1):

I have not used it but http://www.iredmail.org/ seems to fit your bill.